# I can't install BackUps in a Live Ubuntu USB drive

Tags: live-usb

When I try to install BackUps, it pops up a message saying: `Package name deja-dup-backend-gvfs could not be resolved`.

Is there a way to fix/work around this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In live system you need to add `universe` repository by

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt update
```

It is not enabled there, but is enabled in an installed system.

Comment: Thanks Pilot6, but although it did show universe to be activated for everyone, Backups is still giving me the same error :(

Comment: What is the Ubuntu version?

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Comment: Run `sudo apt update`.

Comment: That did it! Thanks a bunch P6 :)

Comment: That was a bit obvious, but I should have added that.